# Not able to select the first row after applying a filter in a grid while using Selenium with java [tricky situation]

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am getting this strange scenario.

Been searching for a long time without success, what is going on?

**Let me explain you:**

> I am trying to create an automation in a webpage, i have to enter a
> specific value in a dinamic table and after performing a "ENTER" event
> it is necessary to select the first row shown:

[image]

---

After running my code i got this but the row shown is not been selected, it is stuck:

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Script_codes {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Me\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://stage.nbm2.test/backend");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("linea");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();
    
    }
}
```

I have tried many different ways but it seems not to be working, what can i do?

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: We can't debug this code since `https://stage.nbm2.test/backend` is not reachable

Answer (score 1):

I would first try the following to see if timing is the issue:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Script_codes {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Me\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://stage.nbm2.test/backend");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("test");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("linea");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();
    
    }
}
```

If this works, I expect it will be fairly simple to identify which step(s) needs extra time. For this wait,  I suggest you implement the `WebDriverWait` class for better stability and execution time.

Comment: All these `Thread.sleep(1000);` is not a good idea...

Comment: @Prophet I'm not suggesting to implement this code. I'm offering it as a debugging effort which would probably make pretty clear if this is a timing issue (and I think it is)

Comment: Why not to use `WebDriverWait`s explicit waits?

Comment: I suggested that at the end of my answer, certainly that could be a best practice, but I couldn't write it in the code since I didn't know what EC I ought to wait *for*

Comment: When you are going to click on an element you obviously want that element to be clickable, no?

Comment: Most likely. Feel free to make any edits you feel improve or add to what I have.

Comment: Thank you :) But instead of this I'd prefer to debug the solution on real page, but the given here url is not reachable ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247809/discussion-between-c-peck-and-prophet).

Comment: Hey pal, no.. it is not working. You cannot access the webpage because it is not exposed

Comment: It throws an error message on my IDE when i use "Thread.sleep(1000);". It says: "Unhandled exception type InterruptedException"

Comment: Otherwise, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73641379/selecting-row-from-filtered-grid-not-working-in-selenium-java-tricky?noredirect=1#comment130042599_73641379

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved my problem by using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
```

instead of:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();
```