# Selecting row from filtered grid not working in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, magento2

I've been struggling with this situation for a long time. I'm using a MAGENTO 2 website (it is a multi language page).

**I'm using SELENIUM & JAVA with chromedriver**

> I am trying to create an automation in a webpage, i have to enter a
> specific value in a dinamic table and after performing a "ENTER" event
> it is necessary to select the first row shown:

**This is the table:**

[image]

**Take a look at this .gif**

[image]

---

**I should be able to click on any row after after applying a filter:**

[image]

**Note:** That's where my program is not working, it wont click on the filtered row.

My automation is not able to click on the row within the label name "linea":

**This is my automation working so far:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Script_codes {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\Me\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://stage.nbm2.test/backend");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("test");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-magento-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("linea");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();
    
    }
}
```

How can i solve this? am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday. We can't help here since we have no access to that site to debug your code.

Comment: Hey @Prophet i added some gif to make my question clear but you cannot access that site that all.

Comment: @Prophet have you seen the gif i posted?

Comment: I'd suggest writing some pseudocode to describe the steps needed to automate that process. As well as where the problem is. Also your last click is using multiple class names so use css selector this driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click(); should be driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-label.col-frontend_label")).click();

Comment: I saw your gif. This does not help debugging your code.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan how can i implement WebDriverWait class to wait a few seconds after "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);" is performed?

Comment: @Prophet i was able to solve this. I used: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click(); instead of driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this:
I used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
```

instead of:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("col-label col-frontend_label")).click();
```

Thank you all!

Comment: It is great you could resolve your problem yourself!

Comment: You helped me, guys. It was a silly questions but i am doing my best :)